# The forum deleted a post without saying why

Tags: community-standards

I am a member of a forum concerned with camping, caravanning and campers and I applied for insurance of my camper which was duly granted.  A day or so latter it was withdrawn without reason so I asked.  The reply was that the underwriters declined to insure people over 80 years of age so I complained to the Underwriters who refused to justify their stance on the cop out grounds that it would breach their confidential base.
I wrote a post criticising the underwriters saying that the forum should not deal with such organisations and my post was simply deleted with no reason given and they refuse to say why after a number of requests.
Is there any control that supervises forums that I can complain to?

Comment: No, I don't know of any. And if you don't mention what forum or country, this is hard to answer anyway.

Comment: Not an answer about your forum but a suggestion about your situation.  There are a number of cowboy insurers in the UK camper market.  You will be better served by posting a review on the likes of Trustpilot.  It is likely to reach more eyeballs.  Remember that many forums are sponsored by these insurers - that can also lead to deletion of negative posts.

Answer (score 9):

Anybody can set up a forum using whatever rules that person wants.  There is no overall authority over forums.  Forum owners are bound by the laws where they and their servers live (for example, laws about handling young users, copyright, and so on), but that's it.

There is no law that says that the owner of a forum has to host all submissions or explain deletions.  If you want to find out why your post was deleted, your best route is to politely and constructively use whatever path they provide for issues about the forum -- a meta site (like Stack Exchange), a "talk" page (like Wikipedia), or a contact link.